# How to execute a function variable

Tags: javascript

I have read this but there is no answer for my question: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Suppose I have a function variable and would like to call it in an if statement.

```
    var myFunc = function() {
        // very long code
    }
    if (true) myFunc;
```

Of course the above if statement would not work. How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the MDN JavaScript Guide to learn the basics about functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions.

Comment: Of course you are right. I just have a bad example to illustrate my problem. Let me rethink for a better example. :)

Answer (score 3):

You just have to invoke it as a function:

```
myFunc();
```